# Filtering on foreign key table's attribute

Tags: django, django-models

These are my relevant models..

```
class Books(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    edition = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
       unique_together = ('name', 'edition',)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name



class Items(models.Model):

    book = models.ForeignKey(Books)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'item_seller')
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'item_buyer', null=True,blank= True)
    requestee = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name = 'item_requestee',blank= True)
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.book.name
```

And this is the part in view fuction where I am trying to filter on foreign key table's attribute

```
 book_item = Items.objects.filter(book__name==q)
```

Where q is a string a get from user.

But I am getting error - `book__name not defined`. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to use '=' and not '=='.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [boolean operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) `foo==bar` where you should be using an [assignment operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/assignment_operators_example.htm) `foo=bar`.

Don't do:

```
 book_item = Items.objects.filter(book__name==q)
```

Instead do:

```
book_item = Items.objects.filter(book__name=q)
```

When calling filter you want it to look through all the `Items` that have been created and return the `Items` that have a `Book` that has a `name` `= (equal)` to `q` (or what ever search variable you're looking for).